# Multi Exports in next.config.json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, progressive-web-apps

I want to add **withPWA** and **withTypescript** together, but i don't know how to config them...

this is my ***next.config.json*** code :

```
const withPWA = require("next-pwa");

module.exports = withPWA({
  pwa: {
    dest: "public",
  },
});
```

and

```
const withTypescript = require('@zeit/next-typescript');

module.exports = withTypescript();
```

these configs only work alone...how can i make them work together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const withPWA = require("next-pwa");

const withTypescript = require('@zeit/next-typescript');

const config = {
    pwa: {
      dest: "public",
    },
}

module.exports = withTypescript(withPWA(config));
```

Use like this

Comment: thank you very much, it workrs fine now...
but what should i ido if i have more than two packages to export???

Comment: you are welcome. I dont understand your comment. Please explain